# How to copy images from leaflet in gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, leaflet

Setting my gulp, as I'm using leaflet, I need to copy the images in leaflet folder in bower_components. I'm trying to do this:

```
gulp.task('leaflet', function () {
  return gulp.src(path.join('bower_components', 'leaflet', '/**/*.{png}'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.clientDist, '/img/')));
});
```

But it doesn't copy anything, what I'm doing wrong?